# Possible to calculate the width/height of a rotated matrix?

Tags: android, matrix, rotation, scale, dimensions

If I use this:

```
mCamera.rotateY(45);
mCamera.getMatrix(mMatrix);
mMatrix.preTranslate(-pivotX, -pivotY);
mMatrix.postTranslate(pivotX + centerX, pivotY + centerY);
```

And do:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, mMatrix, null);
```

Then the drawn picture will be taller and slimmer and the matrix will be nicely applied to the whole picture. Now, is there any way to calculate the rotated size? I want to fit the image by scaling it and now when I rotate it some of the top and bottom is clipped because of the parent's constraints. Thanks!

EDIT:

What I am going to do is spin the image and the range for rotateY will be from 0 to 90.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could easily let the matrix map the corners of your bitmap and then calculate the bounds, as the mapped corners will be the max / min for x and y coordinate. Maybe you can do it without too many `if` clauses :)

**Edit:**
Check out

```
RectF r = new RectF(/*your bitmap's corners*/);
matrix.mapRect(r);
```

That way you should get `r`'s new size.

Answer (score 0):

If you stick to 45° then Pythagoras is the key

Comment: great will try, but you see I am going to make a spin so the range will be from 0 to 90. Any suggestions on what formula to use?

Comment: @NikkyD: That might be a good method for exactly ONE purpose, but try to code for reusability.